# Здравствуйте ,есть файл с ИНН сотрудников, заплатой за первое полугодие и за второе, нужно вывести ИНН сотрудника с наибольшей за за 1-е полугодие

Tags: python

Вот мой код но он выводит неверный ответ:

```
def salary():
    infile = open("C:/Users/OWNER/Desktop/3/salary.txt","r",encoding="utf-8")
    arr = []
    arr1 = []
    max = 0
    num = 0
    
    arr = infile.readlines()
    
    for i in arr:
        if i and i != "\n":
            num = i.split(",") 
    
    for summ in arr1:
        if (max<int(summ[1])):
            max = int(summ[1])
            num=summ
    print(num[0])

salary()
```

[image: так выглядит файл в блокноте]

Может быть проблема этом кусочке кода:

```
for i in arr:
    if i and i != "\n":
        num = i.split(",")
```

но без него программа совсем не работает :(
Буду благодарна за любой совет, спасибо!

Comment: Начните с `import csv`.

Answer (score 0):

Создаете список списков для каждой строки, и далее определяете наиболее из них.
Далее пример кода:

```
import csv

with open('file.txt', newline='') as file:
    salaries = csv.reader(file, delimiter=',')
    salaries = [[int(num) for num in lstt] for lstt in salaries]
    max_salary = max(salaries, key=lambda x: x[1])
    print(max_salary)
```

Comment: в строке `list_of_lists` не нужны квадратные скобки.

Comment: @n1tr0xs верно, а ещё ведь можно сократить на одну строку, только ведь не понятно будет)
```content = list(map(int, x.strip().split(','))) for x in salaries```

Comment: If you’re not using the `with` keyword, then you should call f.close() to close the file and immediately free up any system resources used by it.

Comment: Начните с `import csv`.

Comment: всем спасибо, исправил

Answer (score 0):

замените

```
num = i.split(",")
```

на

```
arr1.append(i.split(","))
```

Comment: Начните с `import csv`.

Comment: @0andriy зачем?

Comment: Потому что там всё есть, а входной файл в этом формате, если вы не заметили.

Comment: @0andriy Моя цель исправить код автора

Comment: Ну так вы всегда будете рыбу за автора ловить...